# Get specific day's date based on the week number and the year

Tags: php, date, php-7.1

I'm getting the year and the 'week-of-the-year' from the external source, which I'm not able to change. I'd like to get the date of Monday and Sunday of that concrete week. For now I've got the below code, but it seems pretty complicated.

```php
<?php

// simulate the server data
$year = date('Y');
$week = 19;

$weekNow = (int) date('W');
$weekDiff = $week - $weekNow; // can be positive or negative
$daysDiff = $weekDiff * 30;

$dayInDesiredWeek = (int) date('N', strtotime($daysDiff . ' days'));  
if($dayInDesiredWeek !== 1) {
    $daysDiff += $daysDiff > 0 ? -($dayInDesiredWeek - 1) : $dayInDesiredWeek - 1;
}
$monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($daysDiff . ' days'));
$sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($monday . '7 days'));
```

Is there any other (simpler) method I can use to get the same results? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the easiest solution I've seen so far, when I was reading the [PHPDocs of DateTime Object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php).

So the steps are:

1. Create `new DateTime()` object
2. Run it's `setISODate` method with params: ($year, $weak, $offsetFromMonday)
3. then run `format` method and get the desired date

So, all together:

```
$monday = ($dt = new DateTime)->setISODate($year, $weak, 1)->format('Y-m-d');
$sunday = $dt->setISODate($year, $weak, 7)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: As no other answers were provided I'm marking this as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dt = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2017W01"));
```

use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
 $dt = new Carbon($dt);

 var_dump($dt->startOfWeek());
 var_dump($dt->endOfWeek());
```